# ORB arm compute library

Tags: arm, computer-vision, gpu, feature-extraction, feature-detection

The ARM compute library has an attractive set of mature, tested functions. Has anyone managed to move ORB feature detection and description over to an ARM Mali GPU? I have found a CPU only implementation that achieves real-time performance [here](https://github.com/0xfaded/pislam), but surely a GPU implementation would bring better performance?

Comment: I'm not very sure it's worth the trouble. It depends what you are doing, but I imagine that ORB features are mostly useful in a SLAM context (although I think there are better alternatives), and in those systems the optimization (backend) usually is the most expensive part. So I'm not sure that there would really improve anything by moving feature detection which is far from a bottleneck to expensive hardware (that if by some miracle, you can use in a project, wouldn't better be spent doing deep learning). And here is another point: If you have a GPU, just do dense reconstruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARM compute library is focused on efficient implementation of convolution neural networks, opposed to classical computer vision methods such feature extraction and description - see [this issue in the Compute Library repository](https://github.com/ARM-software/ComputeLibrary/issues/267)  for further details and a interesting performance result in a benchmark with the Compute Library.